# Value gets changed upon comiting. | CallableStatements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, callable

I having a weird problem with a DAO class and a StoredProcedure, what is happening is that I use a `CallableStatement` object which takes 15 `IN` parameters, the value of the field `id_color` is retrieved correctly from the HTML forms it even is set up how it should in the `CallableStatement` setter methods, but the moment it is sent to the database the `id_color` is overwriten by the value `3` here's the "context":
I have the following class `DAO.CoverDAO` which handles the `CRUD` operations of this table

```
CREATE TABLE `cover_details` (
  `refno` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shape` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL ,
  `id_color` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL ',
  `reversefold` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0' ,
  `x` decimal(6,3) unsigned NOT NULL ,
  `y` decimal(6,3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `typecut` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cornershape` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `z` decimal(6,3) unsigned DEFAULT '0.000' ,
  `othercornerradius` decimal(6,3) unsigned DEFAULT '0.000'',
  `skirt` decimal(5,3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '7.000',
  `foamTaper` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `foamDensity` decimal(2,1) unsigned NOT NULL ,
  `straplocation` char(1) NOT NULL ',
  `straplength` decimal(6,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `strapinset` decimal(6,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spayear` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'Not Specified',
  `spamake` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'Not Specified',
  `spabrand` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'Not Specified',
  PRIMARY KEY (`refno`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=143 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 $$
```

The the way covers are being inserted is by a stored procedure, which is the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `putCover`(
                                    IN shape TINYINT,
                                    IN color TINYINT,
                                    IN reverse_fold BIT,
                                    IN x DECIMAL(6,3), 
                                    IN y DECIMAL(6,3),
                                    IN type_cut VARCHAR(10),
                                    IN corner_shape VARCHAR(10),
                                    IN cutsize DECIMAL(6,3),
                                    IN corner_radius DECIMAL(6,3),
                                    IN skirt DECIMAL(5,3),
                                    IN foam_taper VARCHAR(7),
                                    IN foam_density DECIMAL(2,1),
                                    IN strap_location CHAR(1),
                                    IN strap_length DECIMAL(6,3),
                                    IN strap_inset DECIMAL(6,3)
                                    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `dbre`.`cover_details` 
    (`dbre`.`cover_details`.`shape`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`id_color`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`reversefold`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`x`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`y`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`typecut`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`cornershape`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`z`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`othercornerradius`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`skirt`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`foamTaper`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`foamDensity`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`strapLocation`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`strapInset`,
     `dbre`.`cover_details`.`strapLength`
     )
    VALUES
    (shape,color,reverse_fold,
     x,y,type_cut,corner_shape,
     cutsize,corner_radius,skirt,foam_taper,foam_density,
     strap_location,strap_inset,strap_length);
END
```

As you can see basically it just fills each field, now, the `CoverDAO.create(CoverDTO cover)` method which creates the cover is like so:

```
public void create(CoverDTO cover) throws DAOException {
        Connection link = null;
        CallableStatement query = null;
        try {
            link = MySQL.getConnection();
            link.setAutoCommit(false);
            query = link.prepareCall(
                "{CALL putCover(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
                                    );
            query.setByte(1,cover.getShape().byteValue());
            query.setByte(2,cover.getColor().byteValue());
            query.setBoolean(3, cover.getReverseFold());
            query.setBigDecimal(4,cover.getX());
            query.setBigDecimal(5,cover.getY());
            query.setString(6,cover.getTypeCut());
            query.setString(7,cover.getCornerShape());
            query.setBigDecimal(8, cover.getZ());
            query.setBigDecimal(9, cover.getCornerRadius());
            query.setBigDecimal(10, cover.getSkirt());
            query.setString(11, cover.getFoamTaper());
            query.setBigDecimal(12, cover.getFoamDensity());
            query.setString(13, cover.getStrapLocation());
            query.setBigDecimal(14, cover.getStrapLength());
            query.setBigDecimal(15, cover.getStrapInset());
            query.executeUpdate();
            link.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        } finally {
            close(link, query);
        }
    }
```

The CoverDTO is made of accessesor methods, the MySQL object basically returns the connection from a pool.

Here is the pset Query with dummy but appropriate data:
`putCover(1,10,0,80.0,80.0,'F','Cut',0.0,0,15.0,'4x2',1.5,'A',10.0,5.0)` (removed some trailing zeros)
As you can see everything is fine just when I write to the DB instead of `10` in the second parameter a `3` is written. I have done the following:

Traced the `id_color` value to the create method, still got replaced by a 3

Hardcoded the value in the DAO create method, still got replaced by a 3

Called the procedure from the MySQL Workbench, it worked fined so I assume something is happening in the create method, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Where did you "Hardcoded the value in the DAO create method", did you try `query.setInt(2,10);`?

Comment: Should `query.setInt(2,cover.getColor())` be `query.setByte(2,cover.getColor())`?

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Are You Sure the DAO and the table definition are in agreement?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, yes I tried that, still got replaced by the 3.

Comment: @Tony Ennis: Yes the are in agreement, meaning the procedure handles the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in stored procedure declaration:

```
IN color TINYINT(3)
```

change it to:

```
IN color TINYINT
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: @ShahidAzim: Can you elaborate? "The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column."—http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: It shouldn't work, but in this case it is behaving like that. The best is to wait for @Triztian response.

Comment: @ShahidAzim: I've tried it that way, still that nasty 3 gets into the database.

Comment: You can also include suggestions from @trashgod, and just make code more consistent then it will be easier to debug. For instance, these two lines are updating same type (TINYINT) but using different methods

query.setLong(1,cover.getShape());
query.setByte(2,cover.getColor().byteValue());

Comment: Changed it, made no diference, I even tried removing the `byteValue()` method and use the wrapper classes(`java.lang.Byte`).

Comment: OK, now I need to install MySQL, and soon will back to you.

Comment: Don't bother, I figured it out, the actual problem was in the database, as I had vertically partitioned the table and when I tested the procedure I inserted extra records in the `cover_details` table that made their records inconsistent, so I equaled their record count and now I get the desired results. Thank you for your help it actually made it possible to find the solution.

Comment: Glad to know that it is sorted.

Comment: @Triztian: I urge you to consider accepting @ShahidAzim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the atribute definitions `shape tinyint(3)` and `id_color tinyint(3)`, I am surprised to see `PROCEDURE putCover()` having formal parameters `IN shape TINYINT` and `IN color TINYINT(3)`, respectively. Moreover, I'd expect `create()` to use `setByte()`, accordingly.

Comment: I think that could be it, but according to the specification a TINYINT maps to an INTEGER see here <a href="http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html">Java, JDBC and MySQL Types</a>

Comment: Any luck using `setByte()`, as shown above? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Comment: Actually the issue is resolved, see the comments in ShahidAzim's answer.